# Removing CVV from manual entry after scan (or after using keyboard)

Tags: ios, card.io

We don't use CVV to process the transactions as we process recurring payments and storing CVV is against PCI Compliance. We therefore would like to remove this field from the screen not to mislead the user. How can we customize the screen to not require CVV?

We did this through Android using:
 scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false);

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this; setting collectCVV property on CardIOPaymentViewController does it.

```
CardIOPaymentViewController *scanViewController = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPaymentDelegate:self];
scanViewController.appToken = @"bdb50937d5a7473a8c337c33a5e407ef";
scanViewController.collectCVV = NO;
```

Comment: i spent whole day to find that..Thanks @bosist